# 404 page not found in codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, routes, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-2

I am having 404 when I uploaded the codeigniter to server. I tried every known method and still unable to find the solution
My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'lloyd';
```

Controller lloyd.php

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Lloyd extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {       
        $theme = $this->aauth->get_system_var("theme");
        $this->load->view($theme . '/home');
    }
 }
```

Comment: $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; did not work

Comment: It could be your file name as shown in my answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First with your uri_protocol

**Try This**

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**Instead of**

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

File names must have first letter upper case on CI3 versions same with classes.

> Lloyd.php

**Instead of**

> lloyd.php

With base url all ways good to use **/** at end also.

> `$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';`

Make sure you have the htaccess file on the main directory of your project.

Comment: Lloyd.php worked, codeigniter 2 does not accept this naming convention

Comment: A few things changed now. The user guides for codeigniter 3 & 2 now here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs